# ffmpeg concatenate ts files without losing quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one file `main.mp4` which I split into two mp4 files; `first_half.mp4` and `second_half.mp4`. Using ffmpeg I then merge three files one at the front: one at the middle of `first_half.mp4` and `second_half.mp4`, and one at the after `second_half.mp4`

In order to join the files I first convert them to `.ts` format then join them using the concat protocol. The problem is that the quality becomes horrible and pixelated. After inspecting the split fragments I found out that their quality was okay and the quality only depreciated when I converted to `.ts`.

How can i keep the quality of the ts files same as the original files?

I have also tried concat demuxer but it maintains quality but only works for first file as it ends up distorting subsequent files.

Here are my commands:

```
// cut first half
$cmd ="ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:15:00 first_half.mp4 -y";

shell_exec($cmd);

//convert to ts
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i first_half.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts in first_half.ts -y -b:v 1000000";

shell_exec($cmd);


//cut second half

$cmd ="ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:15:00 -t $length second_half.mp4 -y";

shell_exec($cmd);

//convert to ts

$cmd = "ffmpeg -i second_half.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts in second_half.ts -y -b:v 1000000";

shell_exec($cmd);

//transcode the "slices"

$cmd = "ffmpeg -i front.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts in front.ts -y -b:v 1000000";

shell_exec($cmd);

$cmd = "ffmpeg -i middle.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts in middle.ts -y -b:v 1000000";

shell_exec($cmd);

$cmd = "ffmpeg -i end.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts in end.ts -y -b:v 1000000";

shell_exec($cmd);

//concatenate them

$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "concat:front.ts|first_half.ts|middle.ts|second_half.ts|end.ts" -c copy   output.mp4 -y -b 10000000';

shell_exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 3):

In all the 'transcode' commands, remove the `in`

e.g. `-f mpegts in first_half.ts` --> `-f mpegts first_half.ts`

Now, none of your commands are actually transcoding since you have specified `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`. To actually transcode, remove `-vcodec copy`. You can also skip the intermediate MP4s.
e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:15:00 first_half.ts -y
```